# Speed up a rails database query using postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, activerecord

I am trying to speed up a Rails query that is consuming a lot of time I reload the page.

I have this in the rails view:

```
<% if current_account.subscribed? and current_account.subscription.plan.id == 2 %>  
  <div class="flex items-center bg-blue-100 rounded-lg px-2 mb-2 shadow-lg data-controller="tooltip" data-tippy-content="Clases reservadas este mes" data-tippy-delay="0" data-tippy-arrow="true" data-tippy-size="regular" data-tippy-animation="fade">
    <div class="mr-2 flex-shrink-0 text-3xl md:text-2xl">
      
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="text-3xl md:text-2xl font-bold">
        <%= @lessons_basic_count %>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And this is the query I run on the controller:

```rb
@lessons_basic_count = @mylessons_lessons.where(datetime: Time.at((current_account.subscription.latest_payment.created if current_account.subscription.latest_payment).to_i)..(Date.current + 30.days)).size
```

It's a query that looks on the table `mylessons` which contains lessons a user has booked in the actual period of their subscription.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the SQL that is generated?  If you go to the PostgreSQL console and enter in `EXPLAIN <SQL here>` what does it show?  Maybe you need an index for a column or set of columns on this table.

Comment: `EXPLAIN for: SELECT "lessons".* FROM "lessons" INNER JOIN "mylessons" ON "lessons"."id" = "mylessons"."lesson_id" WHERE "mylessons"."user_id" = $1 AND "lessons"."datetime" BETWEEN $2 AND $3 [["user_id", 18], ["datetime", "2021-06-28 12:50:20"], ["datetime", "2021-07-28"]] QUERY PLAN`This is the SQL query without the .size at the end

Comment: How did you define `latest_payment`? The name suggests that a subscription `has_many :payments`. If you determine the latest payment by loading all payments instead of using a query things could be slowed down considerably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The info that comes after `QUERY PLAN` in the `EXPLAIN` output is what matters.  Could you include that output in your question?

It looks like you might want a dual-key on your `mylessons` table for `user_id` and `datetime`.  You would add that in a migration with something like:

```rb
add_index :mylessons, [:user_id, :datetime]
```

You also want an index on `mylessons.lesson_id`.  That could be added with something like:

```rb
add_index :mylessons, :lesson_id
```

Comment: After QUERY PLAN I get this `Hash Join (cost=46.76..127.95 rows=8 width=506) Hash Cond: (mylessons.lesson_id = lessons.id) -> Seq Scan on mylessons (cost=0.00..81.13 rows=109 width=4) Filter: (user_id = 955) -> Hash (cost=46.54..46.54 rows=65 width=506) -> Seq Scan on lessons (cost=0.00..46.54 rows=65 width=506) Filter: ((datetime >= '2021-06-19 09:26:54'::timestamp without time zone) AND (datetime <= '2021-07-28 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)) (7 rows)`

Comment: It looks like you also need an index on `mylessons.lesson_id`.  Your explain plan isn't using any index conditions.  When it says `Seq Scan` that means it has to scan the entire table.  Your query is scanning both your `mylessons` table and your `lessons` table.